# Sum multiple arrays into one

Tags: google-sheets

Been trying to tackle this issue for a couple days and without much progress.

I have a multiple date filter (or a query) which filters a date array: i.e. array of dates from 12.2020 to 01.2022 and multiple filters range (01.2021-02.2021, 05.2021-09.2021).

This process filters the dates and produces multiple filtered arrays. The pic of how it looks is attached.

The formula used to produce arrays =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((($F$5:$S$5>=QUERY($B$3:$D$4;"select C where B = "&D8&""))*(F$5:$S$5<=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER($D$3:$D$4;$B$3:$B$4=$D$8))));1;0))

As you can see, it generate multiple arrays, depending on the amount of filters applied.

My question is following is it possible to sum these arrays into one with one formula? So I would get 1 array instead of multiple.

EDIT 1: [Link for clarity](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wu9Sq6aTd3scg8wwwOPxvRt_fQF31MXwTAh2fjkoqrs/edit?usp=sharing)

[Screenshot of google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXQJS.png)

Comment: It might be helpful for us to share a sample.

Comment: @MikeSteelson yep, that definitely would be =)

Comment: added in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=transpose(mmult(arrayformula(VALUE(transpose(  ARRAYFORMULA(IF((($F$5:$S$5>=QUERY($B$3:$D$4,"select C where B = "&D8&""))*(F$5:$S$5<=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER($D$3:$D$4,$B$3:$B$4=$D$8)))),1,0)) ))),sequence( 2,1,1,0)))
```

### Explanation

I encapsulate your formula and your result in a MMULT formula to get the sum of each column

```
=transpose(mmult(arrayformula(VALUE(transpose(F8:S9))),sequence(2,1,1,0)))
```

Comment: Yep!
Much appreciated, I'll have to make it a bit more dynamic depending on the filter count, but nonetheless it does what it should.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(COLUMN($B$3:$D$5)^0,(($F$5:$S$5>=QUERY($B$3:$D$5,"select C where B = "&D8&""))*(F$5:$S$5<=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER($D$3:$D$5,$B$3:$B$5=$D$8))))))
```

[image]